# Drupal 6 preprocess blocks & nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-blocks

I build a `BLOCK` that sits on a right side of the website and is available for whole site.

Also I got a many `CONTENT_TYPE NODES like (pages, news,gallery, files)`.

How can I modify `_preprocess_xxxxx` and which one, so I can let my `BLOCK` know which `CONTENT_TYPE` is currently displaying.

so then my `BLOCK` displays var $section = `top 10 download` for `CONTENT_TYPE==files`;
and for `CONTENT_TYPE==news`, I will see `latest news` in my block var $section.
etc, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a preprocess to solve this, but since you have made your own block it is a lot easier to handle this from within the block code.

You can use [`arg`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/arg/6) to check if the block is being displayed on a node, and then check what type that node is. You'll have to disable the cache for the block though, or else it wont work.